# Minimal requirements to get a ring $(R^n,+,\times)$ from a ring $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (throughout this post, by "ring" I'll mean not necessarily an "associative ring"). If we denote by $+$ the addition component-wise, we get that $(R^n,+)$ is an abelian group ($n$ integer, $n \ge 2$) with additive unit $\bar 0:=(0,0,\dots,0)$. If we further request:

- $R$ with unit $1$;
- $(R^n,+)$ left $R$-module

then $\forall \bar u \in R^n, \bar u = u^i\bar e_i$ (summation convention), where $\bar e_i:=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ (the only $1$ is in the *i*-th entry).

Now, suppose that we want to build up in $R^n$ a multiplication, "$\times$", such that:

1. $(R^n,+,\times)$ is a ring;
2. "$\times$" is bilinear on $R$.

Then, $\bar e_i \times \bar e_j=\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k$ completely defines the multiplication under construction.

A wishlist for $(R^n,+,\times)$, and the according constraints on the general $\alpha$s, could start with:

- $(R^n,+,\times)$ associative ring:

$$\alpha_{jk}^l\alpha_{il}^m=\alpha_{ij}^l\alpha_{lk}^m, \forall i,j,k,m \tag 1$$

- $(R^n,+,\times)$ ring with unit $\bar e_1$:

$$\alpha_{1j}^k=\alpha_{j1}^k=\delta_j^k, \forall j,k \tag 2$$

($\delta_l^m$ is Kronecker symbol).

**Example: $n=2$**. $(R^2,+,\times)$ is a ring with unit $\bar e_1$ if and only if (from $(2)$):

$\alpha:=\alpha_{22}^1, \beta:=\alpha_{22}^2$

$\alpha_{11}^1=\alpha_{12}^2=\alpha_{21}^2=1$

$\alpha_{12}^1=\alpha_{21}^1=\alpha_{11}^2=0$

(For $R=\mathbb{R}$, so loosely constrained, these coefficients should include either complex and split-complex numbers cases, according to the fulfilment or not of additional constraints.)

These coefficients seemingly fulfill $(1)$, so that -at least for $n=2$- $(R^n,+,\times)$ ring with unit $\Rightarrow (R^n,+,\times)$ associative ring

My questions are:

1. Is the requirement 2. (..."bilinear"...) essential to build up a ring out of $R^n$? (I have the feeling to have requested it just to pop into linear algebra and make things somehow accessible to my background)
2. Is it true in general that ring with unit implies associative ring?

Comment: Also not necessarily commutative?  You'd need to say a little more about what you meant by bilinear then too.

Comment: For 2): having an identity does not imply associativity. For example, the [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) are a nonassociative ring with identity (and needless to say there are associative rings without identity.)

Comment: Commutativity: I'm not sure to have gotten your point, but I had indeed the following doubt. If we want both $u^iv^j\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k$ and $v^ju^i\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k$ represent the generic $\bar u \times \bar v$, then it must be $(u^iv^j-v^ju^i)\alpha_{ij}^k=0, \forall k$: does it necessarily mean $R$ commutative?

Comment: $R$-bilinearity is a somewhat slippery notion when $R$ is not commutative and/or acts differently on the left and on the right of $R^n$. But without $R$-bilinearity, I am also not convinced that the $\alpha_{ij}^k$ determine the whole multiplication on $R^n$.

Comment: From a practical point of view (I've got poor knowledge of the theory behind), I'd say that the slipperiness comes from the two possible orders in which $R$-scalars may pop out left-side from a two factor $R^n$-multiplication: if we want the result to be irrespective of such order, then $R$-commutativity is a sufficient condition. What I can't conclude is if it is necessary, too.